# Can expose Cloudify shell commands as a API?

Tags: cloudify

In the integration perspective, can we expose Cloudify shell commands as API call?. For instance, 
 http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:8067/apiv1.0/cloudify/?command=bootstrap-cloud&provider=openstack

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Exposing the Cloudify CLI as an API is a good way to integrate with Cloudify. 
This is especially true if you are planning to bootstrap cloudify clouds on demand so the Cloudify REST API is not available yet.

You should also consider the security implications of allowing the CLI commands to be specified in the URL, as users will be able to make calls that will install/uninstall services.